# Not all values of `Url.Page(values)` show up in the Get method of the page model

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, blazor-server-side, querystringparameter

The following code builds a clickable URL which is emailed to user:

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
    pageHandler: null,
    values: new { userId = response.Id, code = response.EmailConfirmationCode, returnUrl = returnUrl },
    protocol: Request.Scheme);
```

All the params / values show up in the clickable URL in the email. However, when the user clicks the URL, the page model `Get` method only gets the first `userId` param:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId, string code, string returnUrl)
{
 //
}
```

I have tried `public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync([FromQuery] string userId, [FromQuery] string code, [FromQuery] string returnUrl)` but to no avail.

`HttpContext.Request.Query` is empty too.
What do I miss?

Comment: Have you tried using `[FromQuery]` on parameters of Get method? Furthermore, you can check how your endpoints are configured, probably only the first parameter is caught

Comment: Tried `public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync([FromQuery] string userId, [FromQuery] string code, [FromQuery] string returnUrl)` but to no avail. Tell me more about the "first parameter is caught".

Comment: Can you show an example of the clickable URL that gets constructed any route template that you might have applied to the ConfirmEmail page?

Comment: `https://iam.mydomain.com/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=<GUID>&amp;code=<very long string>&amp;returnUrl=%2F_Host`. No route template.

Comment: Have you tried something like `[HttpGet("ConfirmEmail/{userId}/{code}/{returnurl}"]`?

Answer (score 1):

Your generated URL is getting HTML-encoded at some point in the process and the query string `&` separators are converted to their equivalent HTML entity (`&amp;`). This is fine if you want to display the query string in an HTML page, but not if you want to read the query string.

If you are using Razor at any point to generate the HTML email, use `Html.Raw()` on the URL to prevent it from being encoded.

You should find that `https://iam.mydomain.com/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=<GUID>&code=<very long string>&returnUrl=%2F_Host` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `public Task SendMailAsync(MailMessage message);` variant of the interface setting `IsBodyHtml` to `true` solves the problem.